# How prove $ \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}>\pi$?

Tags: real-analysis, real-numbers

How prove that $ \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}>\pi$? Maybe some easy way?

Comment: Not sure that it helps, but it is equivalent to $(\pi^{2}-5)^{2} < 24.$

Comment: Approximating $\sqrt{2}$ and $\sqrt{3}$ up to three decimal places is very easy. Approximation of $\pi$ can be done using upper and lower Riemann sums of $2\sqrt{1 - x^2}$ function.

Comment: Some solutions [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/84381/geometric-proof-for-inequality).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Assuming known inequality $\pi<\frac{22}{7}$, it's easy to proceed by proving that $\frac{22}{7}<\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}$:
$$\frac{484}{49}<5+2\sqrt6,$$
$$\frac{239}{49}<2\sqrt6,$$
$$\left(\frac{239}{98}\right)^2<\left(\frac{120}{49}\right)^2=\frac{14400}{2401}<6,$$
$$14400<14406.$$

Comment: you are supposed to provide a succint proof that uses integral or some other estimates and not using 22/7.

Comment: Then it would have been helpful if you said so at the outset.

Comment: @8pir Who said so?

Comment: @8pir The OP never specified a specific way to prove.

Comment: I think the main point of this question is how to approximate $\pi$. The result that $\pi < \frac{22}{7}$ require a bit of work. There is even a wikipedia article on it: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proof_that_22/7_exceeds_%CF%80

Comment: See also http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701822/geometric-explanation-of-sqrt-2-sqrt-3-approx-pi.

Comment: I'm not sure about the inequality proof since you use the assumption that it is true throughout the proof to get your result. I'd say use a proof by contradiction and then prove it false.

Answer (score 7):

Use this:
$$\begin{align}{\pi^2\over6}
&=\sum_{n=1}^\infty {1\over n^2}
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{10}\frac1{n^2}+\sum_{n=11}^\infty {1\over n^2}
\\&\le\sum_{n=1}^{10}\frac1{n^2}+\sum_{n=11}^\infty {1\over(n-1)n}
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{10}\frac1{n^2}+\sum_{n=11}^\infty \left({1\over n-1}-\frac1n\right)
\\&=\sum_{n=1}^{10}\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{10}.
\end{align}$$

Thus we have
$$(\pi^2-5)^2\le\left(\left(\sum_{n=1}^{10}\frac1{n^2}+\frac1{10}\right)\times6-5\right)^2=23.996\ldots<24,$$
and this completes the proof, as Geoff Robinson pointed out.

Comment: Isn't the last infinite sum $\frac17$ instead of $\frac18$?

Comment: @Matteo Oh, sorry. I edited.

Comment: The first equality is nontrivial. Proving it would make this answer much longer.

Answer (score 1):

Use your favorite method to show

$$ \sqrt{2} > 1.414$$
$$ \sqrt{3} > 1.73$$
$$ \pi < 3.144$$

Answer (score 1):

This is just an improved version of The Great Seo's answer.
Since:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^2\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{\pi^2}{18},\qquad\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{1}{n^4\binom{2n}{n}}=\frac{17\,\pi^4}{3240}$$
you only need to check that:
$$\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\frac{\frac{3240}{17}-180\,n^2}{n^4\binom{2n}{n}}<-1$$
that is trivial since 
$$\sum_{n=1}^{3}\frac{\frac{3240}{17}-180\,n^2}{n^4\binom{2n}{n}}<-1$$
yet, and the extra terms are negative. As an alternative, since the archimedean approximation $\pi<\frac{22}{7}$ holds,
$$(\pi^2-5)^2 < \left(\left(\frac{22}{7}\right)^2-5\right)^2 = \frac{57121}{2401}<24.$$