# Prove that $\pi < \sqrt2 + \sqrt3$

Tags: circles, pi

A square inscribed inside of a circle with radius $1$ must have a perimeter $4\sqrt2$. A regular hexagon circumscribed about that same circle has a perimeter $4\sqrt3$. Since we know the circle’s circumference is $2\pi$, we can prove the inequality $2\sqrt2 < \pi<2\sqrt3$.

By averaging the the lower and upper bounds of that inequality, we can find an approximation for $\pi$:
$$\pi \approx \sqrt2 + \sqrt3$$

Since $\sqrt2 + \sqrt3 \approx 3.14626$, and $\pi \approx 3.14159$, it is clear that $\pi$ is less than $\sqrt2 + \sqrt3$. But how can we prove that without knowing the value of $\pi$?

Comment: This is proved also in [this duplicate](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/701822/geometric-explanation-of-sqrt-2-sqrt-3-approx-pi), namely $$
3+\frac{\sqrt{2}}{10}<\pi<\sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}
$$

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How prove $ \sqrt{2}+\sqrt{3}>\pi$?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/884424/how-prove-sqrt2-sqrt3-pi)